# Combine 2 function of javascript / Type script into one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I Have one Date variable, and I am updating it every second to make it live.

Now here is my variable.

```
var stationdate = new Date(data.localTime);
```

My **Javascript** code to update it per second.

```
window.setInterval(function () {        
    stationdate = new Date(stationdate.setSeconds(stationdate.getSeconds() + 1));            
  }, 1000);
```

And My **Type Script** code to return it to Angular UI.

```
window.setInterval(() => this.time = stationdate, 1000);
```

**My Issue.**

It works perfectly if both functions are seprate.

but it stops working if I combine them.

see below.

```
window.setInterval(function () {        
    stationdate = new Date(stationdate.setSeconds(stationdate.getSeconds() + 1));
    this.time = stationdate;            
  }, 1000);
```

**AM I MISSING SOMETHING WITH FAT ARROW OF TYPE SCRIPT?**

What should be the proper function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `function` has it's own `this` context. So your `this` refers to another object in the function expression. With `arrow function` it refers to the outer `this` which contains that `arrow function`.

Use arrow syntax and there is no necessary to use `window` prefix behind the `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(() => {        
    stationdate = new Date(stationdate.setSeconds(stationdate.getSeconds() + 1));
    this.time = stationdate;            
  }, 1000);
```

For more read **[Arrow function vs function declaration/expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)** - this is one of the main concepts in Javascript.

Comment: @Bharat Read that SO answer and you will understand

Answer (score 1):

In your combination of both function your not using an arrow function, which leads to the context of `this` is `window`. Use an arrow function to keep the outer context of `this`.

```
window.setInterval(() => {        
    stationdate = new Date(stationdate.setSeconds(stationdate.getSeconds() + 1));
    this.time = stationdate;            
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setInterval( () => {        
    stationdate = new Date(stationdate.setSeconds(stationdate.getSeconds() + 1));
    this.time = stationdate;            
  }, 1000);
```

In your code this has wrong context.
The fat arrow function is feature of ES6 and has nothing to do with TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, `this` refers to the inner-scope of your function not the outer scope where your variable is most likely defined. Therefore as others have suggested, you need to use the lambda symbol.

Also, since you're using AngularJS it would be preferable to use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead of `window.setInterval()`.

Note that by using `$interval`, a `$scope.$apply()` will be made to do dirty-checking if your variable has changed and then update the UI. This is not a given when using `window.setInterval()`. Alternatively, you can still tell `$interval` to not use `$apply` if that is something you need.

Comment: I am using Angular 4.3, and It seems $interval is not easy to use in 4.3.

Comment: @Bharat, ahh judging by the usage of ES5 and the tag 'AngularJS' I assumed you were using AngularJS 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

It common bug of using callbacks. All in javascript has own 'this' context (except arrow functions). Just for systems function this===undefined.

So proper way is use arrow function (as it shown above). Best for modern browsers (or transpiled code).

```
 window.setInterval(() => {        
    stationdate = new Date(stationdate.setSeconds(stationdate.getSeconds() + 1));
    this.time = stationdate;            
  }, 1000);
```

Another way to store 'this' is binding context:

```
window.setInterval((function () {        
    stationdate = new Date(stationdate.setSeconds(stationdate.getSeconds() + 1));
    this.time = stationdate;            
  }).bind(this), 1000);
```

Or more explanation:

```
window.setInterval(
    (function(){console.log(this.hello);}).bind({hello:'hello!'})
   , 1000);
```